# Is there any way to change the name of Content-type Header?

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers

I've developed a REST API which is being consumed by a different application, but the consumer is sending me `LED_TransferContentType` instead of `Content-Type` header because of which consumer is receiving status code `415`. Is there a way I can manipulate my controller to interpret `LED_TransferContentType` as `Content-Type`.

Comment: You can define a filter which will add the content-type header with the right value read from your custom header

Comment: @akuma8 that seems like a feasible solution.I'll try it.Thanks.

Comment: @akuma8 the problem is since there's no `Content-Type` Header in request it's taking default value 'text/plain' is there any possible way to manipulate the header value?